# Обзор тестовых JavaScript фреймворков

Tags: юнит-тесты, javascript, framework

Здравствуйте.

Провожу сравнение javascript-фреймворков, пригодных для написания тестов.
Особенно интересуют фрейворки, в которых можно писать UI-тесты.

Помогите, пожалуйста, **просто продолжить список**: AngularJS, JSSpec, jsTestDriver, JsUnit, Jasmine...
Буду очень благодарен если оставите **комментарии** по опыту работы с конкретным фреймворком:
что в нём удобно, с чем были проблемы.

Всем заранее спасибо.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/looking-for-a-better-javascript-unit-test-tool

Comment: http://casperjs.org/

Comment: Котик_хочет_кушать, спасибо вам БОЛЬШОЕ. Обзор отличный.
Если кто-нибудь знает не упомянутые в статье выше фреймворки (например, AngularJS), отпишитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: QUnit — совсем простой, совместим с grunt (мне хватает за глаза).

Comment: RubaXa, спасибо!